# C# gcnew object and long running SQL query

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a process to select and run a SQL query. Sometimes (most times it works fine) this results in a crash at the end of the original calling function. The process goes like this (all method calls in instantiated classes); (Note; just listing processes due to actual code being 1000s of lines. I will try to provide more detail if needed)

Method call to QueryPicker (params) (c#)
QueryPicker calls cs_query_picker (params) (c++, in a loaded dll, shared by other services at the time)
cs_query_picker declares 100s of variables then calls QueryPickerWrapper (params) (c#)
QueryPickerWrapper uses gcnew

```
string ^Params = gcnew string;
if (param != nullptr) 
Params->Str = gcnew String (params);
```

QueryPickerWrapper then calls MyQueryPicker (Params) //made with gcnew
This finds the SQL query and runs it. It can take up to 1200ms (not horrifyingly long really)
MyQueryPicker then sets Params (with the query result) and returns true (that something set)
QueryPickerWrapper when true is returned, sets the pointer

```
if(params != nullptr)
strcpy_s(params, PARAM_LEN+1, (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Params->Str));
```

QueryPickerWrapper then returns true
cs_query_picker returns a 1 when it gets a 1 from QueryPickerWrapper, else it moves to older code (1998 stuff, would use the 100s of declared variables) to set params. In all the crashes, QueryPickerWrapper always returns a 1.
QueryPicker receives the 1, finishes the method using the param that was passed back, then crashes.

I've never caught an exception with the crash (I have a try/catch around it) and with the windows event log, it says
Faulting modulename: clr.dll, version:4.0.30319.34209
Exception Code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x001a149f

To the best of my research this is a stack overflow. However, I don't know how it would be happening. I fell since the issue is intermittent (some times also every hour, sometimes not for days) that it is a relation between when the garbage collector runs and how long the SQL calls takes before returning.

The question:
How is this occurring and what can I do to fix it?

This is compiled and run in .NET4.0

Comment: You're probably better off tagging C++CLI rather than C++. Regardless, this looks dodgy `(char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Params->Str)`. Maybe an `IntPtr` can convert to a c-style string, but I doubt it. I think you may be missing a step like a `toString` method call.

Comment: I was close. [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi(v=vs.110).aspx) you're missing a `.ToPointer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string ^Params = gcnew string;
if (param != nullptr) 
    Params->Str = gcnew String (params);
```

I can't tell what's a typo here, and what might be a coding problem.

- `Params = gcnew string`, followed by `Params->Str`. Neither [`System::String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) nor [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) have a member named `Str`. Is Params a struct, or something like that?
- `Params`, `param`, and `params`. You've got three almost identically named variables. If they're all typos of each other, then I have no idea what `params->Str = gcnew String(params);` is supposed to do.

.

```
strcpy_s(params, PARAM_LEN+1, (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Params->Str));
```

OK, this one I can answer. Your main problem is that you're allocating a new HGlobal in `StringToHGlobalAnsi`, and never releasing it (a memory leak). You could keep the pointer around and free it, but I prefer to use `std::string` as a temporary variable. Everyone knows how to deal with a `std::string`, so there's no new rules to learn.

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

std::string temp = marshal_as<std::string>(source);
strcpy_s(destination, PARAM_LEN+1, temp->c_str());
```

Comment: After looking at the c++ file's use of the Marshel line, I feel you are correct that a memory issue is happening here. I've rewritten the queryPicker to not use the c++ dll and the crash has gone away. Thank you.  Also, sorry my sudo code sections were difficult.